# PurgeTempDestinations does not have an implementation

Tags: c#, .net, stomp

I am trying to implement ActiveMq to connect stomp to consume message, but I am getting the following issue in

```
Apache.NMS.IConnection oConnection = oConnection =
factory.CreateConnection(Configuration.MQTTUserName,Configuration.MQTTPassword);
```

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled HResult=-2146233054 Message=Method 'PurgeTempDestinations' in type 'Apache.NMS.Stomp.Connection' from assembly 'Apache.NMS.Stomp, Version=1.5.4.3215, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=82756feee3957618' does not have an implementation.

But the ActiveMq [Documention](http://activemq.apache.org/nms/msdoc/1.6.0/vs2005/Output/html/M_Apache_NMS_IConnection_PurgeTempDestinations.htm) tells that, PurgeTempDestinations is an optional operation and for NMS providers that do not support this functionality the method should just return without throwing any exceptions.

Comment: I haven't used ActiveMQ, but is it possible that that assembly only contains interfaces and base classes, and that your project needs to also reference another assembly -- maybe one that contains the implementation for an NMS provider?

Comment: Can you inspect the `Apache.NMS.Stomp` assembly with [`ildasm.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) to see if it contains IL code for that method?

Answer (score 2):

The Apache.NMS.Stomp v1.5.4 is compatible with Apache.NMS v1.5.1, and the later releases seems to be incompatible.

I've got the same problem, and I fixed that problem by uninstalling the version v1.7.1 and reinstalling the Apache.NMS version v1.5.1.

Hope it helps

Tiago